# How do I "escape" a time in a todo entry so that it doesn't show up on the time grid?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have some to-do entries that have a "time-like" string (i.e something like `7:00`) as part of the entry text. The problem is that org-mode is interpreting that substring as a time, and is treating that as part of the timestamp for the to-do entry. Is there a way to escape this text so that it doesn't get interpreted as a timestamp?

**Edit**: I see that the [org-mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Time_002dof_002dday-specifications.html) specifies

> In the headline of the entry itself, a time(range) may also appear as plain text (like ‘12:45’ or a ‘8:30-1pm’).

Is there a way to disable this behavior, or failing that, indicate to org-mode that it should *not* interpret a particular piece of text as a timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `org-agenda-search-headline-for-time` to nil to disable that behavior for all agenda items.